# How to save a specific value in discord.js for it to be used later

Tags: javascript, database, discord.js

I am trying to make a system where you can beg for money in discord.js currently I have it generate a random interger and send it in the channel. I want each user to have a wallet of sort that stores there money, how would I do this.

Comment: You could use something like a database. You can just search for databases in Google, and you can find lots of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need a database, I would recommend [MongoDB](https://www.mongodb.com/) and the [Mongoose Library](https://mongoosejs.com/) as a simple one.